# How to reset a date attribute in an object in Maximo REST API

Tags: rest, maximo

I want to change the deligatefromdate/deligatetodate in the person object in IBM's Maximo REST API.
If I want to set a date I use this request:
POST maximo/rest/mbo/person/12345/?_format=json&delegatefromdate=2020-12-02

My person object then is returned and the value in delegatefromdate is:
"DELEGATEFROMDATE": {
"content": "2020-12-02T00:00:00+01:00"
}

But now I want to remove the date, I dont want a delegatetodate/delegatefromdate.
I have tried:

```
POST maximo/rest/mbo/person/63006/?_format=json&delegatefromdate=
Value is not changed

POST maximo/rest/mbo/person/63006/?_format=json
Value is not changed

POST maximo/rest/mbo/person/63006/?_format=json&delegatefromdate=null
Error: Error 400: BMXAA4143E - The date format is not valid. Use the date format defined by your locale, or use the calendar control to enter a date.

POST maximo/rest/mbo/person/63006/?_format=json&delegatefromdate=NULL
Error: Error 400: BMXAA4143E - The date format is not valid. Use the date format defined by your locale, or use the calendar control to enter a date.

POST maximo/rest/mbo/person/63006/?_format=json&delegatefromdate=~null~
Error: Error 400: BMXAA4143E - The date format is not valid. Use the date format defined by your locale, or use the calendar control to enter a date.

POST maximo/rest/mbo/person/63006/?_format=json&delegatefromdate=~NULL~
Error: Error 400: BMXAA4143E - The date format is not valid. Use the date format defined by your locale, or use the calendar control to enter a date.

POST maximo/rest/mbo/person/63006/?_format=json&delegatefromdate=0
Date is set to: "2000-12-01T00:00:00+01:00"
```

I have tried with and without &addchange=

So my question is, how do I clear this date?
In the GUI I just erase the value and save and it is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM has a record of this problem as [APAR IV93341: UNABLE TO UPDATE FIELD TO NULL THROUGH THE MAXIMO REST API](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IV93341). Someone found it on Maximo 7.5.0.7, and the APAR fix was included in 7.6.0.8.